# How do I get the percentage of used storage in the UNIX server

Tags: shell, unix

I want to get the only Percentage of the Disk space in the UNIX server

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       457G   90G  344G  21% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           798M  1.1M  797M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   23M  2.0G   2% /run/shm
cgroup          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I am using the following command to get the Percentage data

```
df -h > space.txt

space=`head -2 space.txt | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f15 | sed 's/%.*$//'`
```

Is there any command to get the "Used percentage" directly

Comment: I do object to categorising this as **general computing hardware and software**. This question, and many like it, is a programming question, and highlights the fact that we do lack an effective cross-platform API for dealing with "low level" system information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
used=$(df / | awk 'END{print $5}')
echo $used
56%
```

Rather than running `df` without specifying the filesystem you actually mean and then looking for it in a mass of lines, I specify `/` as the filesystem up front, then I know the result will be on the last line. I take advantage of that by using `END` in `awk` to get the 5th field in the last line only.

Comment: Please have another try.

Comment: Good thinking.  However, on systems with long device names you may still end up with split lines, and the column numbers may be off.  `df` is really unpredictable across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Using [gnu coreutils `df`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/df-invocation.html):

```
$ df -P | awk '/\/dev\/sd/ { print $1, $5, $6 } '
/dev/sda3 54% /
/dev/sda2 95% /media/data
```

Note the use of the `-P` flag to force each mount to print on exactly one line.
This is a requirement for predictable results when scripting.

This example includes both device `$1` and mountpoint `$6`.  You can drop either or both as you wish.

> ‘-P’
>
> ‘--portability’
>
> Use the POSIX output format. This is like the default format except for the following:
> The information about each file system is always printed on exactly one line; a mount device is never
> put on a line by itself. This means that if the mount device name is more than 20 characters long
> (e.g., for some network mounts), the columns are misaligned.
>
> The labels in the header output line are changed to conform to POSIX.
> The default block size and output format are unaffected by the DF_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE
> and BLOCKSIZE environment variables. However, the default block size is still affected by
> POSIXLY_CORRECT: it is 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, 1024 otherwise. See Block size.

Comment: I appreciate your point about portability, and the `-P` switch and I would also generally try and make my scripts robust, but please be aware that `-P` on Mac OSX actually changes the blocksize rather than standardising the output in a POSIX-y way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I haven't actually checked the code, but OSX' [`df`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/df.1.html) is based on `BSD` code and the FreeBSD [`df` man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=df&sektion=1) specifically refers to `-P` being required by POSIX, so while both man pages may only state that it affects the blocksize my guess is that it actually adheres to the complete output format required by POSIX, otherwise they would knowingly and openly break POSIX which I am pretty certain (/hoping) is not the case.